# Creating VBA function in Personal Notebook results in NAME? error

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a VBA function to combine cells with a comma delimiter and trying to save it to my personal notebook so that it is available to all notebooks.  For some reason I could get it working when I use the "Record Macro" feature but not when I use VBA.

VBA:

```
Function combine(WorkRng As Range, Optional Sign As String = ",") As String
'Update 20130815
Dim Rng As Range
Dim OutStr As String
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.Text <> "," Then
        OutStr = OutStr & Rng.Text & Sign
    End If
Next
combine = Left(OutStr, Len(OutStr) - 1)
End Function
```

...and here is a screenshot showing where it's saved:

[image]

but when I type `=combine(CELL_RANGE_GOES_HERE)` it results in `#NAME?`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you intend to do with `Optional Sign as String = ","`?  I believe that's causing the error.

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with VBA and copied the code from a blog.  I'm assuming it's an optional argument that is used at the delimiter when combining the selected cells

Comment: Try entering the formula as `=PERSONAL.XLSB!combine(I2:I8)`.  You may also want to change `If Rng.Text <> "," Then` to `If Rng.Text <> Sign Then` (if the cell contains the value of `Sign` then don't include in the return string).

Comment: May also be worth looking at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815205/use-personal-xlsb-function-in-new-workbook

Comment: when I add the workbook prefix it says `Cannot find 'PERSONAL.XLSB'. Copy from:` and opens a "open file" window.  I'm not even sure where that file is stored on macs

Comment: Ahhh - on a Mac.  No idea then, sorry.  But.... hopefully this will work... to find out where it's stored open the Immediate window, select a module in the Personal workbook and type `?Thisworkbook.FullName`.  Should give you the path to the workbook - if it's the same on the Mac.

Comment: Quick test, just remove the `Optional` part so it's just your range. Then change `OutStr = OutStr & Rng.Text & Sign` to just `OutStr = OutStr & Rng.Text & ","`.  Does it still throw the error?  Anyways, just realizing, I think the main issue is as @DarrenBartrup-Cook - your Excel doesn't seem to be "seeing" the Personal.xlsb.  Another quick test is to put that code in an Excel's workbook module (so, create a new Workbook, and put that in "Module1" say and just see if it works there).

Comment: @BruceWayne still no luck.  I think  it has to do with making the notebook visible like you said, but I'm just not sure how to accomplish that.  And if I have to do that in every notebook than there is really no benefit to putting it in a public notebook.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I'm not sure what the "Immediate window" is

Comment: So it seems as though macros work, but functions don't.  How might I change this into a macro and simply replace the first cell of the selected cells with the final combined product?

Comment: @JeremyThomas - I just mentioned to put it in a new workbook as a troubleshooting method, just to test if the VBA code works properly. If the code works in a new workbook (as you have it, or with taking out the `Optional` part as I mention) then we know the problem is with the `Personal.xlsb` part, and not the code itself.

Comment: Any command entered into the immediate window is immediately executed.  Again, not sure what it would be on the Mac - press `Ctrl+G` in the VBA window or selecting `View ~ Immediate Window` from the toolbar.

Comment: @BruceWayne when I create the function locally, it works fine.  It's not an issue with the function, just an issue of locating it