# I am getting a #Name? Error when I run my macro

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function ConvertDate(r As Range) As String
    Dim d As String
    d = Mid(r,5,2) & "/2019"
    Select Case Mid(r,4,1)
    Case "C"
        ConvertDate = "1/" & d
    Case "D"
        ConvertDate = "2/" & d
    End Select
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim FR As Long
    FR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Range("A1:A" & FR).Formula ="=ConvertDate(H1)"
End sub
```

What do I need to change to fix this error?

Comment: `"=ConvertDate(H1)"` is the String that reads exactly those characters (an equal sign followed by a "C" and so on). Try: `Range("A1:A" & FR).Value = ConvertDate(Range("H1"))`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I think OP wants to write the *formula*.

Comment: Are you writing the formula to a sheet in a different workbook than the one containing the `ConvertDate` code?

Comment: No they are both stored in my personal macro workbook. And correct, I am trying to write the formula with a UDF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815205/use-personal-xlsb-function-in-new-workbook

Comment: Is this code in a module or the sheet backend?

Comment: @AJD it's in the personal workbook...