# How to recreate the following excel function as a custom function in VBA: =IF(ISBLANK(I2), "late", IF(I2 > H2, "late", "on time"))

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Here is What I have currently, I am returning a #NAME error after trying to call the function as follows:

> =OnTime(H2, I2)

here is my function - first iteration and current - after trying a few things from related threads:

## =IF(ISBLANK(I2), "late", IF(I2 > H2, "late", "on time"))

## 1st iteration

```
Function OnTime(RqstDate, ShipDate)

If IsEmpty(ShipDate) Then

    OnTime = "late"

ElseIf ShipDate > RqstDate Then

    OnTime = "late"

Else

    OnTime = "On Time"

End Function
```

## current iteration

```
Function OnTime(RqstDate As Date, ShipDate As Date) As String

    If IsEmpty(ShipDate) Then

        OnTime = "late"

        Exit Function

    ElseIf ShipDate > RqstDate Then

        OnTime = "late"

        Exit Function

    Else

        OnTime = "On Time"

        Exit Function

End Function
```

The function as typed directly in Excel works fine but not my VBA attempt to replicate it, what am I missing to get this functioning properly?

Comment: You are missing an `End If` in your function

Comment: There may be another issue using `IsEmpty` with a `Date` since Ive had it happen where the `Date` will return a value of 12:00:00 which would cause the `If IsEmpty(ShipDate) Then` to return `false` and cause the function to not behave as expected, but that also depends on how you are passing the value for each of those dates.

Comment: End If statement added but still receiving the same result (both original and current iteration)

Comment: Take a look at my answer below and see if that works.

Comment: in the case of the IsEmpty, I dont think it will be an issue as the generated worksheet I am trying to filter does not input any value into shipdate column if there is not a date in the database so the blank cells should definitely be returning empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my question, I wanted to create this custom function and have it be usable across multiple worksheets. There was a scripting issue here in the form of a missing End If, (Credit to Zack E for pointing that out) but was not what I was looking for exactly.

The solution that I found met my needs was linked by Scott Craner in the comments and provided by Egalth in this thread:

[Use Personal XLSB Function in New Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815205/use-personal-xlsb-function-in-new-workbook)

Though the function can be saved in personal.xlsb, the file name needs to be called with the function in order to use it in a new workbook, making it almost as clumsy as typing the full Excel version. I wanted a function that acted like any other pre-installed function: simply type =ontime([input],[input]) and be on my way.

The most elegant way to accomplish this was by creating a and installing simple add in. I retrieved most of the information on how to do this - with one exception - in this guide linked by Egalth:

[If you want a truly general-purpose UDF, always available without either prefix or reference, you can install it as an add-in.](http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/create-an-excel-add-in-for-user-defined-functions-udfs)

The one exception is that (at least in Excel '19) I was not able to just "Save As" and simply type .xlam.... I had to select "Save As", and then select "More options". From here I was able to select "Excel Add-in" from the "Save as type" drop-down menu.

Now I have a functioning addin for custom formulas alongside my personal.xlsb for Macros!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an **End If** at the end:

```vb
Function OnTime(RqstDate As Date, ShipDate As Date) As String
    If IsEmpty(ShipDate) Then
        OnTime = "late"
        Exit Function
    ElseIf ShipDate > RqstDate Then
        OnTime = "late"
        Exit Function
    Else
        OnTime = "On Time"
        Exit Function
    End If 'THIS IS MISSING
End Function
```

edit: where is your function located? **Create a module in your Excel file and store your function there**. Functions created in ThisWorkbook will not be visible in the worksheet.

(This has been tested and is working fine in the worksheet)

Comment: Saved in Module 1 under modules in my personal.xlsb, I reduced my data to only the request date and shipdate and tried the above code again, still returning name error

Comment: @Writhe: Try a simpler case. Create a Module 1 in Excel file and Write a simple function there:  

`Function MyTestFunction()
    MyTestFunction = "Test"
End Function`

See if MyTestFunction works in the worksheet.

Comment: @Writhe if it is your personal.xlsb you will need to use: `=Personal.xlsb!OnTime()` or follow the instruction on the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815205/use-personal-xlsb-function-in-new-workbook

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner I didnt even see that this was in a file with the .xlsb extension.

Comment: Solved! This is what I was missing @ScottCraner thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since Im not sure how you are passing the dates to that function and am guessing you are passing it from a value in a cell.  Adding the `ByVal` and `Optional` to the Function will specify that you want to use the value and not the reference within the Function; the Optional For the `ShipDate` will allow you to run the function without the ShipDate argument.  As Scott pointed out you will need to use `=Personal.xlsb!OnTime()` for your function call in the workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Sub testDate()
    Dim OrderDate As String
    Dim ShippedDate As String

    OrderDate = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    ShippedDate = Sheet1.Range("B1")

    sheet1.Range("C1") = OnTime(OrderDate,ShippedDate)


End Sub

Function OnTime(ByVal RqstDate As String, Optional ByVal ShipDate As String) As String

    If ShipDate = "" Then

        OnTime = "late"

        Exit Function

    ElseIf ShipDate > RqstDate Then

        OnTime = "late"

        Exit Function

    Else

        OnTime = "On Time"

        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I copypasta'd this directly to try it and am still returning the same error. you correct I am passing the dates from a cell (starting cell h2 and i2, trying to repeat this function down these columns) as I said if the excel formula is typed directly in Excel it works fine I am just trying to replicate that to VBA so I can make a shortcut, if there is another way to save this function without handwriting the code (similar to recording a macro) that would be valuable advice as well.

Comment: When you say getting the same error what error specifically are you getting?

Comment: @Writhe when you say "Error" are you getting a runtime error?  Also what cell or row of cells is getting the value from the `OnTime` Function?

Comment: Issue was in attempting to call the function from personal.xlsb file in current workbook, VBA script is running fine (with the addition of End If, thank you). I have created an add in so that I can call this function directly instead of trying to save it in my macro workbook and all is well.

Comment: @Writhe glad it all got sorted out.