# Is it possible to prevent code available in personal.xlsb?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been self-teaching myself VBA for a couple of years now (working on it on and off to make my work life easier). I'm usually able to find answers to my questions on this forum, but not this one.

I have a lot of 'example' code in my own personal.xlsb. For instance I have a public sub with a modified messagebox with standard caption etc I always like to make visible, referred to as *PublicSub_MyMsgBox*

Often, the automation I create, will be used by my colleagues as well. I would create a specific workbook with specific buttons for a specific goal. I would copy the required code into a module in this shared workbook. The workbook would therefore have a module with the sub *PublicSub_MyMsgBox* as well.
Another sub in this shared workbook will have a line to call *PublicSub_MyMsgBox*.

How can I be sure that when I test a code created in this shared workbook, it does not use the *PublicSub_MyMsgBox* from my own personal.xlsb, but actually only uses the code from the workbook?
(to be able to verify that I have indeed copied all relevant code into the workbook for my colleagues to use as well).

Thank you very much for your help!
Linda

Comment: If you didn't add a reference from the new book to your personal.xlsb, then it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer lead me to another search and helped me find this post as well, which helped me further understand :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815205/use-personal-xlsb-function-in-new-workbook

Comment: @GSerg: Even with a reference to personal.xlsb, in case of procedures having the same name, VBA will run the one from the workbook where the calling sub runs, without finding any conflict.

Answer (score 0):

No code from personal.xlsb will run even if a reference to pers. workbook exists! **You can be sure that no code from personal.xlsb will be run, instead of the one inside the workbook where the call is made**.

Even if you added a reference to your personal.xlsb, for identic macro names VBA will choose the one in the workbook where the code runs. To check that, please, try the next scenario:

1. Create in your personal workbook the next macro:

```
Public Sub MyMsgBox()
   MsgBox "Hello from Personal workbook!"
End Sub
```

2. Then create the next macro in a standard module of your new workbook:

```
Sub MyMsgBox()
   MsgBox "Hello from This workbook!"
End Sub
```

3. Create a simple checking `Sub`, of course, in the new workbook, add a reference to your personal.xlsb workbook and run it:

```
Sub testMyMsgBox()
   MyMsgBox
End Sub
```

4. It will run the `Sub` in your workbook. Now, comment the `Sub` from your workbook and run `testMyMsgBox` again. It will ran the procedure from personal.xlsb...

Comment: That doesn't really answer "How to make sure no code from personal.xlsb is involved", does it? It only states that for macros that have been copied with the same name and accessibility, leaving out all the other options that may lead macros from personal.xlsb to still be involved.

Comment: @GSerg: I would say that the answer is implicit... I mean, is should be read as "No code from personal.xlsb will run even if a reference to pers. workbook exists. **You can be sure that no code from personal.xlsb will be run, instead of the one inside the workbook where the call is made**. But you maybe are right. I will state it at the beginning of the answer...

Comment: You are missing at least two possibilities. One is that you have a button on a sheet attached to a [macro from another workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31815353/11683). That works with or without a reference. Another, is that there is a macro from personal.xlsb that is being called because the macro has been overlooked when copying the code to the target workbook (which is exactly the case you are reproducing in your step 4 above). So while the statement in bold is correct, it doesn't help in determining if there is any code from personal.xlsb that is being called after all.

Comment: @GSerg: I would not agree in both cases... If you have a button assigned to a macro from another workbook, it is not the case in discussion. In such a case, **you assigned on purpose a macro from another workbook**, even personal.xlsb an no danger to run something from the workbook calling it. In the second case, the relevant aspect is that copying the the code from personal workbook, even modifying it **as it is the case in discussion**, there is no danger that the call will be taken by personal.xlsb 'mother' macro...